# Anomalous calculation about stellar collision

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

> Suppose two bodies of mass $m$, one of them is fixed and the another is free to move,they are separated by a distance $l$ initially and the system is at rest. What would be the speed of the free body if the separation between them goes to zero.

My approach - set up the differential equation since it's in one dimension,it'd be easy to solve,so I get the initial result which says that speed goes to infinity when the separation goes to zero which I think should be instead equal to the initial potential energy.

Answer (score 0):

You are quite right with your method and your result. The initial potential energy is negative, and it gets more negative as they approach each other.

Comment: Aren't these two things contradicting each other?The soln to the differential says that the speed goes to infinity at separation ->0 but according to the energy conservation, it's kinetic energy at zero separation should be equal to its initial potential energy.

Comment: No. The kinetic energy is equal to the change on potential energy: $K=V_{initial}-V_{final}$. But, as I said, $V_{final}$ is infinitely large and negative, so $K$ is infinitely large and positive.

Comment: Ah I got it,that means that speed does tend towards infinity since both energy Conservation and the differential equation says so,am I right?

Comment: Yup! But my opinion is very slight compared with the evidence you have already amassed! The differential equation and Energy!!